# Why am I getting “Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'” from jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I searched through the site and I still cannot figure out my problem. I upgraded an application from JQuery 1.3.2 to jQuery 1.12.4 to fix another problem.

However, I can't generate a popup div. I get an Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'” error.

My div is :

```
<div id="mydiv" title="pop up window" class="dialog">
   <jsp:doBody />
</div>
```

The div pops up using an href which calls the following javascript :

```
$(function() {
$('#mydiv').dialog({
  bgiframe: true,
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 500,
  width: 600,
  modal: true,
  resizable: true,

  open: function (event, ui) {                    
      $(this).load(detailComposition.do?methode=consulter&id=14);
  }  
});
});

$('#mydiv').dialog('open');
```

Hi don't understand the error and also I don't know why it complains about the close method since it is not in the code.

Can you help me ?

Thanks,

Pierrick

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with `close`, but that you open and call the `dialog` before the page completes loading. Also, `load` should be a String value that defines the URL.

Try:

```
$(function() {
  $('#mydiv').dialog({
    bgiframe: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 500,
    width: 600,
    modal: true,
    resizable: true,
    open: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).load("detailComposition.do?methode=consulter&id=14");
    }
  });
  $('#mydiv').dialog('open');
});
```